# Can I use React.useCallback inside another React.useCallback?

Tags: reactjs, optimization

There is a component that renders user card

```js
import React from "react";

const User = React.memo(function({id, name, isSelected, ...other}) {
  return (
    <div {...other}>
      {name} - {isSelected && "Selected"}
    </div>
  );
});

export default User;
```

and a parent component that renders user cards

```js
import React from "react";

function Application() {
  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([
    {id: 1, name: "John Doe #1"},
    {id: 2, name: "John Doe #2"},
    {id: 3, name: "John Doe #3"}
  ]);
  const [selectedUserId, setSelectedUserId] = React.useState(null);

  return users.map((user) => {
    const isSelected = selectedUserId === user.id;

    return (
      <User
        {...user}
        key={user.id}
        isSelected={isSelected}
        onClick={() => setSelectedUserId(user.id)}
      />
    );
  });
}

export default Application;
```

The task is "Avoid re-rendering other user cards after select a user"

I've tried to use `React.useCallback` hook, there is my first implementation

```js
import React from "react";

const User = React.memo(function({id, name, isSelected, ...other}) {
  return (
    <div {...other}>
      {name} - {isSelected && "Selected"}
    </div>
  );
});

function Application() {
  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([
    {id: 1, name: "John Doe #1"},
    {id: 2, name: "John Doe #2"},
    {id: 3, name: "John Doe #3"}
  ]);
  const [selectedUserId, setSelectedUserId] = React.useState(null);

  const handleSelectUser = React.useCallback((userId) => () => {
    setSelectedUserId(userId);
  }, []);

  return users.map((user) => {
    const isSelected = selectedUserId === user.id;

    return (
      <User
        {...user}
        key={user.id}
        isSelected={isSelected}
        onClick={handleSelectUser(user.id)}
      />
    );
  });
}

export default Application;
```

in this case, `React.useCallback` returns an anonymous funtion that has a new reference

**Result: all user cards still re-rendering after each click**

I decided to wrap this anonymous function in `React.useCallback`

```js
import React from "react";

const User = React.memo(function({id, name, isSelected, ...other}) {
  return (
    <div {...other}>
      {name} - {isSelected && "Selected"}
    </div>
  );
});

function Application() {
  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([
    {id: 1, name: "John Doe #1"},
    {id: 2, name: "John Doe #2"},
    {id: 3, name: "John Doe #3"}
  ]);
  const [selectedUserId, setSelectedUserId] = React.useState(null);

  const handleSelectUser = React.useCallback((userId) => {
    return React.useCallback(() => {
      setSelectedUserId(userId);
    }, []);
  }, []);

  return users.map((user) => {
    const isSelected = selectedUserId === user.id;

    return (
      <User
        {...user}
        key={user.id}
        isSelected={isSelected}
        onClick={handleSelectUser(user.id)}
      />
    );
  });
}

export default Application;
```

The problem was solved, but there is another question, did I do it right? React team says: *Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions*, what side effects can I get?

P.S. Do NOT touch `User` componentt

Comment: It doesn't make any logical sense to use React.useCallback inside another React.useCallback. Hooks are effectively instance variables tied to a components lifecycle.

Comment: @AdamJenkins, thanks for your comment, but I still do not understand can I use this for production? `React.useCallback` returns an anonimous function with new ref on each render, how to solve it?

Comment: @AdamJenkins, i understand tha in this example there is no need for optimization, but I would like to know

Comment: To be clear, no, you did not do it right, you cannot call hooks inside of hooks (and expect it to work in a consistent and stable way)

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation for why you can't call hooks inside of hooks (and expect it to work consistently and eliably)

Why can't you call hooks inside of hooks - go here for a super deep dive with more context than I need to provide in this answer https://overreacted.io/why-do-hooks-rely-on-call-order/

Your solution works because, despite "breaking the rules" the call order to your hooks are always the same....until users are added or removed from state.

You can definitely use your solution as it's written. But what happens in the circumstance where you need to [change the number of users](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bzdyhr?description=A%20create-react-app%20project%20based%20on%20react%20and%20react-dom&file=src%2FApp.js&title=React%20Starter)?

---

No, you can't use hooks inside of hooks. It may "work", but React tells you it won't work reliably and you're doing it wrong. Hooks must be called at the top level of a component of the top level of a custom hook.

You were on the right track, but the solution to your problem is to

1. Use the argument provided to the callback function as the source of the element that was clicked on AND
2. If you cannot modify the User component, then you've got to provide some data on the `div` element to let you know what user element was clicked.

Here's what it looks like:

```
function Application() {
  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([
    { id: 1, name: 'John Doe #1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'John Doe #2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'John Doe #3' },
  ]);
  const [selectedUserId, setSelectedUserId] = React.useState(null);

  // this callback is referentially stable - it doesn't change between renders because it has no dependencies
  const handleSelectUser = React.useCallback((e) => {
    setSelectedUserId(+e.target.getAttribute('data-userid'));
  }, []);

  return users.map((user) => {
    const isSelected = selectedUserId === user.id;

    return (
      <User
        {...user}
        data-userid={user.id} <- this line
        key={user.id}
        isSelected={isSelected}
        onClick={handleSelectUser}
      />
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: **Your component just needs to call it with the user id that’s passed into it** - How to do this without an anonymous function? `onClick={() => setSelectedUserId(user.id)}` will not work

Comment: @John `onClick={setSelectedUserId}`

Comment: this won't work, `onClick` is a function, which takes `event` as the first argument, (`React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>`), now you are trying to pass the first argument of this event into the `setSelectedUserId` function

Comment: @John it’ll work just fine - think harder about how you can use this onClick function in your user component. You’re correct, you cannot put it **directly** on the div

Comment: @John ok, you’ve made an edit to your original question that has caused me to update my answer

Comment: The question has not been edited. I knew that you could use a custom date attribute, but I deliberately did not do it to see if it could be solved in another way. React documentation says that you can't do this, but there is no sensible explanation why you can't do it, now it works and does not cause problems, so what can go wrong? Where I can find an explanation of this behaviour? You don't give a clear answer, just mention the documentation (which I already read before) and give a solution with a data attribute, which is just a solution, not an explanation

Comment: @John - that's a fair comment. I've updated with more context (far more context by pointing to an article) and a code example that, if a requirement is added to your code in the future, makes it non-scalable, whereas it otherwise would be if you followed the rules of hooks.